# Rails mongoDB add new key-value pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB on Rails. If I want to add a new key-value pair in the existing collection, what is the syntax to do it? Suppose the collection name is User, is it similar to

```
User.create(:name => "john")
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Mongo_mapper or Mongoid (then you must have an User model)?

```
#mongo_mapper
User.create(:name => "John")
```

With ruby driver, is something like this:

```
collection = db["User"]
collection.insert(:name => "John")
```

But first, you need to make a connection, and choose database

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html